# Unity2019.2b - Adding an element to a List<GameObject> makes the scene player hang and Unity totally unresponsive. Looking for solutions

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, gameobject

Adding an element to a `List<GameObject>` makes Unity hang and unresponsive.

Commenting out the line (which renders the game inoperable, as it is a core component), makes this problem disappear.

Surrounding the problem with a `try { ... } catch (Exception e) { ... }` does nothing different.

The Editor Log only prints the `Debug.Log(...)` directly preceding it and nothing more.

Changing `StraightDict` type to Array or Dict doesn't affect the problem.

There are 3D areas composed of Straight GameObjects, noted `Straight`.

At beginning

```
private static List<GameObject> StraightDict = new List<GameObject>();
```

In `void Start() { ... }`

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {             
    InstantiateStraight();
}
```

And `InstantiateStraight()` is :

```
    private void InstantiateStraight() {
        SectionHandler Previous = SectionList[SectionList.Count - 1];
        GameObject Straight = Instantiate(WorldObjects["Straight"], Previous.GetNextSectionPosition(false), Previous.GetNextQuaternion());
        Straight.transform.SetParent(World.transform, false);
        Debug.Log(Straight);

        try {
            StraightDict.Add(Straight);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Debug.LogError(e);
        }

        SectionHandler SH = Straight.GetComponent<StraightHandler>();
        SH.WorldSpaceIndex = SectionList.Count;
        SH.SetDirection(Previous);
        SectionList.Add(SH);
        CurrentWorldLength += 1;
    }
```

The program ran until 2 days ago without modifying the source code or the Unity version. 
It is a somewhat basic operation that is being done (adding to a List) and should be done without a hitch.
As such I am asking if anyone has a possible solution to my problem.

**EDIT**
As such it seems that my error stemmed from copy pasting a prefab from another project through windows in a way that didn't force the regeneration of the .meta files (Dirty referencing).

Comment: Are you able to set breakpoints through Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code? Alternatively, if you place `Debug.Log` statements after each call, what output is produced in the console?

Comment: I've now done that and found that it was an error in how my prefab was imported (from another project) and the .meta file copied directly alongside it, so it actually qualifies as human error (Dirty reference to other project in the .meta file that was somehow missed by the reimport process).